# Loadrunner & Lightstreamer

Tags: loadrunner, lightstreamer

We have an application which uses LightStreamer to stream data. It does this over HTTP.

I'm trying to performance test this application with LoadRunner.

I have two URLs:
URL 1 creates a session id and stays open, this URL will continue to load
URL 2 uses this session id to make requests. The response of each request will appear on URL1's page.

The issue I am having is that when I make the request for URL 1, I am unable to make subsequent requests while keeping this request open. I tried using the web_concurrent wrapper, but that creates issues because before I can make the request to URL 2 I need the session id which is returned from URL.

Getting the ID isn't an issue, executing a request while the first request is still running is the issue.

Has anyone successfully tested LightStreamer with LoadRunner before?

This was the only thing I could find online whereby someone else was doing the same thing: http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=685960

Unfortunately he no longer works with our company. I tried reaching out to him on LinkedIn but I have not had much luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are looking to test Poll or Push communications which were built into LoadRunner in version 11.50. We actually used a LightStreamer Demo application during development and testing of this feature, and they *should* be picked up at recording time by the Async correlation engine.

If you are using LoadRunner 11.5x and this is not happening, I would be interested in hearing more about the business process.

[Shane Evans](http://twitter.com/ShaneEvansLR)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to respond to me Shane. I appreciate it.

Here is what I have so far:

[code]
web_reg_save_param("p_sessionid",
                  "LB=SessionId:",
                  "RB=\r",
                   LAST);

 web_url("create_session.txt", 
  "URL=<URL TO CREATE SESSION>", 
  "TargetFrame=", 
  "Resource=0",
  "RecContentType=text/html", 
  "Referer=", 
  "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
  "Mode=HTML",
  EXTRARES,
  "URL=<URL TO REQUEST DATA WITH SESSION ID>", 
  ENDITEM,
  LAST);

[/code]

Comment: My next step is to figure out how I parse the responses while this function continues to run ad infinitum.

The responses look like this:
[code]
ction.c(7): t=5506ms: 7-byte response body for "URL" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(7):     PROBE\r\n
Action.c(7): t=6607ms: 59-byte response body for "URL" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(7):     1,1||03:46:29 PM|||22:$215.4200|$$1.9800||||||2,357,903||\r\n
Action.c(7): t=7609ms: 49-byte response body for "URL" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(7):     1,1||||||||$$215.4100|5|$$215.4500||2,358,003||\r\n
[/code]

Comment: The response for the first EXTRARES will always be 1,1, if I make subsequent requests in the EXTRARES piece, then they will be 2,1 and 3,1, all the way to n,1.

I need some way of trying to measure the latency here between making the initial request and getting the response. Tricky - does anyone have any ideas?

I also need to figure out a way of ending the web_url() request after 6 minutes. Using the web_set_timeout("STEP", 600) will just end the web_url call in an error - that is not really what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

I am all set here except for one specific part.

The rest is as follows: 
    web_url("create_session.txt", 
        "URL=URL", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "Resource=0",
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=", 
        "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML",
        EXTRARES,
        "URL=URL", ENDITEM,
        "URL=URL", ENDITEM,
        "URL=URL", ENDITEM,
        "URL=URL", ENDITEM,
        "URL=URL", ENDITEM,
        "URL=URL", ENDITEM,
        "URL=URL",ENDITEM,
        LAST);

As explained above each of the EXTRARes URLS respond in the format 1,1, 2,1, 3,1,... so I use web_reg_find to count those occurrences.

My last question is this: I use web_set_timeout("STEP", 60); to make the web_url function stop after 60 seconds however this results in: Action.c(20): Error -27728: Step download timeout (60 seconds) has expired     [MsgId: MERR-27728]

Is it possible to do this gracefully, as it is setting the return of my Transaction to a fail status as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the extreme delay. Mix of vacation and other factors...

Does your request timeout impact the script's ability to complete? If not, you can use lr_continue_on_error function, with one of the following options:

```
0 = LR_ON_ERROR_NO_OPTIONS
1 = LR_ON_ERROR_CONTINUE
2 = LR_ON_ERROR_SKIP_TO_NEXT_ACTION
3 = LR_ON_ERROR_SKIP_TO_NEXT_ITERATION
4 = LR_ON_ERROR_END_VUSER
```