# Strategy to do performance testing of lightstreamer

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, neoload, lightstreamer

I have an high transaction application which uses LightStreamer to stream data. It does this over HTTP.

I am not sure how to do performance testing of this (Strategy). Can someone please help me on this?

Googling yield some result but they are not in detail of approach and mainly gives info about one tool.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Lightstreamer website this seems more of a data push technology, using websockets and other stack components, rather than a pure "streaming" technology for live video or audio.  Am I missing something?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightstreamer

Comment: yes it is , it can push to browser the live data (e.g. trading price of stocks and indices). There is one discussion around it :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528183/loadrunner-lightstreamer   sample Demo lightstreamer app: http://demos.lightstreamer.com/

Comment: See LoadRunner 12.x websocket support

Comment: any pointer where I can get more information? meanwhile I am trying  trying by Loadrunner async script.

Comment: yes , I have nearly done lightstreamer scripting now, will update this thread after I complete full evaluation on the solution... Thanks James